# Solr : Searching a field containing hyphen

Tags: solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

I am using spring-data-solr(version = 1.4.0.RELEASE) to search a field containing a hyphen but getting zero results. One of my indexed field contains value as "Wal-mart" and when i search for "wal" it gives correct result but on searching for "wal-" i get zero results. I tried adding an escape backslash character before - but it didn't help. Could someone please advise what could be the issue here?

Below is the snapshot of my schema.xml.

```
            <fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: You're missing the top of the index analyzer definition

Comment: @MatsLindh - have added index analyzer definition

Comment: what is your spring-data-solr implementation? how you retrieve solr results?

Comment: @FranciscoSpaeth -  I am using solrTemplate.queryForPage to get search results.    Page<Document> results = solrTemplate.queryForPage(query, Document.class);

Answer (score 5):

Add the preserveOriginal="1" parameter to the WordDelimiterFilterFactory on both the index and query analyzers. Currently generateWordParts will leave you with Wal and Mart from Wal-Mart. preserveOriginal will add the original term Wal-Mart to search on.

Comment: Thanks! adding preserveOriginal="1" fixed the issue.